# .gitignore files which do not have numbered names

Tags: gitignore, glob

I have many files in my directory but I only want files whose names (not extension) solely contain numbers. I understand I need to write a glob pattern (not regex) which matches numbered names files and then negate it.

Example of valid, uploaded files:

```
1312.js
1.go
8.py
2.js
```

Examples of invalid, local files:

```
index.html
text2.txt
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Meta character `[:digit:]` represents digit in the glob syntax. So, write the following into your `.gitignore`.

```
[[:digit:]]*.*
```

Extended Reading

- [Glob tutorial from Bash hacker's wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob)

Comment: Okay but I want to whitelist rather than blacklist "digit" files. Where do I place the negation operator / `!`? If you amend your answer to do so and explain it I will upvote and accept it.